# Why doesn't my html file get my javascript file. load static

Tags: javascript, python, django, static-linking

here is my settings.py:

```
    STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIR = [STATIC_DIR]
```

here is the end of my html page:

```
   {% load static %}
       <script src="{% static '/js/script.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </html>
   {% endblock %}
```

I have a folder `static` and inside it, there are two more folders one is `js` and the other is `css`. But when I try to load it, it always says `"GET /static/js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1795` I have tried many things but it does not work. Someone please help.

Comment: is that you added this in templates TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / "templates"
        ],

Comment: And do BASE_DIR / "static", like this

Comment: does not work. STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR/'static')

Comment: Are other static files working for you? Also is this development or production setting? (i.e. DEBUG = True or False)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is development server (i.e DEBUG = True), then try this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static',
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

If it is production server, then you simply remove the `STATICFILES_DIR`. The [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/deployment/) explains this more in depth.